Add A Single Column CSV To DynamoDb Table Via S3
I have a large CSV file of 265,000,000 domain names, one domain per line. I want to upload this file to AWS S3 and then upload the file to DynamoDb. I have some questions.

Can I make the domain on each line my PK?

Do I need to define a PK in my CSV header? For example, I want to name my DynamoDb domain column, "d". So do I simply put a single "d" in my CSV file header and leave it at that?


d
mydomain1.com
mydomain2.com
mydomain3.com
...etc...


Lastly, do I need to separate each domain with a comma? Or is one domain per line and no comma okay?

Thanks


Can I make the domain on each line my PK?

Yes, so long as each domain in the entire file is unique

Do I need to define a PK in my CSV header? For example, I want to name my DynamoDb domain column, "d". So do I simply put a single "d" in my CSV file header and leave it at that?

Yes, you can define d in the header, or alternatively, you can manually define the header.

Lastly, do I need to separate each domain with a comma? Or is one domain per line and no comma okay?

The built in separators for Importing from S3 are:
, | : | | | \t | ; | " "
You can test it out in a subset of the file to see if it will consider a new line as a space " " however, I suspect you will need to add a comma to each line.
